# How can I remove tintColor of Image component after setting it?

Tags: android, image, react-native, png, tintcolor

I'm creating a simple app for my bachelor thesis in react native and I have these PNG images that the user can move around.

The images can also change tintColor, which works fine and they start out with their original color. The problem happens when I set a tintColor and then try to "reset" it again, then the image just becomes invisible.

[Image when it is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjLWL.png)
[Image after changing to a color then to null again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trkzb.png)

As you can see in the images below, the picture is still there, but just not visible.

The code to set the tintColor in the style looks something like this:

```
             <Animated.Image
                    source={source}
                    resizeMode={'contain'}
                    style={[
                        styles.item,
                        tintColor === null ? {} : { tintColor: tintColor },
                        {
                            transform: [{ scale: imgScale }],
                        },
                    ]}
                />
```

When the images loads, and the value is null, it doesn't set any tintColor, but if I set the tintColor and then go back to null, it just completely removes any colors on it. I've tried different things and so far nothing has worked. I want the user to be able to "reset" back to the original PNG colors, especially for some of them that already have their own colors set.

The images are loaded dynamically from a list when I add them and are draggable.

Comment: Set two styles, styles.item without tintcolor and styles.tintItem with tinntcolor  then switch between them using condition

Comment: hey, thanks for the comment. I tried that already, it didn't work.. because I set the tintColor through a different component (like the half circle popout menu you can see on the screenshot). It's just weird that when it is rendered the first time and tintColor (as a state) is set to null, but when it is rerendered with a new tint and back to null it's invisible. I tried to add a conditional for the style, but then I can't set different colors, and I tried to set one with both the style and the tintcondional that you see above

Answer (score 1):

Give them a key={Math.random} if you wont to reset. But if you want to tint you must give them a static key.
This will solve your problem.

Edit: key={this.state.tintIt?Math.random:'a12'}